# vbscript how to get radio button from cell

Tags: dom, vbscript

I have

```
table.rows(i).cells(0).innerHtml outputs

<INPUT name=group_478 value=2 type=radio>
```

how do I get this input element as a variable using `table.rows(i).cells(0)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you there:

```
table.Rows(i).Cells(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value
```

Or as well

```
table.Rows(i).Cells(0).childNodes(0).Value
```